# HtmlString error for Kendo.Mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Error in Razor View for this line:

@(Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
)

Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures' but it could not be found.

I have upgraded VS 2015 Update 3 and Dotnet Core 1.0.

Is it because of this breaking change?
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/178

Is there any work around to this?

Would Telerik have to do something on their end to resolve this?

I have included the kendo references
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTRAQ.png)

Comment: Depends. Check the dependencies of KendoUI. If it still references the old rc2-final assemblies, then you need to wait for an update or compile it yourself if it's open source

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in the latest version of Kendo.Mvc - 2016.2.630-Preview